# Azure DevOps release issue

Tags: .net, azure-devops, triggers, task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Every build triggers a new release candidate , even if the build was canceled or just partially succeeded.
How can I condition which build to trigger a new release?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. In its current form, this question is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask] and provide us with enough information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, not clear about your question, I have listed three tips:

**1)** You can select some of the required Pipelines and then [edit the pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#branch-considerations) and add the related triggers.

**2)** If you want to run a pipeline and then add a trigger on it with the condition of another build pipeline, you can try this:

Modify the yml file and use stages with condition to trigger the event:

```
resources:
 pipelines:
   - pipeline: test // the name you defined for the current pipeline
     source: xxx // the related another build pipeline name
  
stages:
  - stage: a
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId'], 'xx'))
    jobs:
      - job: A1
        steps:
          - script: xxxx
```

**First**, you should [use resources](https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html) to declare the resource to be used, such as the name of the  related pipelines.

**Second**, use stages with the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#examples). Under the condition, if the second build pipeline succeed, then trigger the stage to execute. You can use this with [build variable Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) to specify which build pipeline as a condition.

[image]

The `DefinitionId` is under the url of your build pipeline.

Then, you can write any operation under the script.

**3)** If you want to combine several build pipelines to trigger a same release, you can [use release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops) to